# Bipolar RC Oscillator does not oscillate

Tags: oscillator, bipolar

[Falstad schematic and simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+5e-11+3.046768661252054+55+5+50%0Ac+112+208+160+208+0+6.8000000000000005e-9+-0.35417029524400334%0Ac+160+208+208+208+0+6.8000000000000005e-9+-0.07365203127486453%0Ac+208+208+256+208+0+6.8000000000000005e-9+0.6169086721656445%0Ar+160+208+160+288+0+1000%0Ar+208+208+208+288+0+1000%0Ar+256+208+256+288+0+1000%0Ar+256+208+256+96+0+8200%0At+256+208+304+208+1+-1+-0.18908634564677662+-0.7297480129904379+204%0Aw+304+224+304+288+0%0Ar+304+176+304+96+0+47%0Aw+256+96+304+96+0%0Aw+112+208+112+176+0%0Aw+160+288+208+288+0%0Aw+208+288+256+288+0%0Aw+256+288+304+288+0%0Aw+304+288+384+288+0%0Aw+304+96+384+96+0%0Ac+304+176+384+176+0+0.0000047+-0.03188088617089413%0Av+512+144+512+240+0+0+40+9+0+0+0.5%0Aw+512+144+512+96+0%0Aw+512+96+384+96+0%0Aw+512+240+512+288+0%0Aw+512+288+384+288+0%0Aw+112+176+304+176+0%0Aw+304+192+304+176+0%0AO+384+176+432+176+0%0Aw+384+288+384+224+0%0Aw+384+224+416+224+0%0Ao+25+64+0+4098+10+0.1+0+1%0A)

[image: Image of schematic from Falstad]

VCC is 9V.

I made hardware version of this first (didn't put too much effort in this simulation) and it's not working. I could read about 3-4 V on CE, so transistor was partially open and seems that it was around Q point. I used 8550 transistor (not sure what D611 under 8550 means).

What could be the reason here? Maybe too small capacitors, maybe too high RC resistors, or maybe ill-suited transistor?

Comment: Schematic looks like you missed a connection somewhere around the collector.

Comment: Get your circuit fixed and never use crossing wires to make a junction.

Comment: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16776723

Comment: also your attenuation is greater than your gain

Comment: The information about "3-4 V on CE" has no meaning without knowing the supply voltage you are using. What is the quiescent current Ic ? This gives information about transconductance and gain of the stage.

Comment: VCC is 9V. Current should be about 70 mA, considering this voltage drop and resistance of 47 Ohm.

Answer (score 0):

Review this picture: -

[image]

Now answer these questions: -

1. What do the white dots inside the orange boxes mean?
2. What's happening with the crossing wires in the purple box?
3. What's not-happening with the crossing wires in the red box?

<sub>As others have pointed out, it seems you also don't have enough gain for this circuit to oscillate - try removing the 100 ohm load and making the 47 ohm resistor more like 220 ohm.</sub>

Comment: Yes, I missed collector wire junction, I thought falstad will create it automatically, but I had to disconnect resistor from collector, connect it with capacitor and then connect this by wire to collector... Sorry for that. In purple box there should be no crossing, and it seems that there are no crossing, right?

Comment: Still I'm not sure about gain vs attenuation... Transistor's beta is 204. And because there is no emitter resistor, gain should be (voltage drop on collector resistor) / (0.026 thermal V) right? With 3-4 Volts on resistor, it should give more than 100 gain. And I read that RC Oscillator amplifier should have 29 or more amplification. Sorry, I'm just really confused about all of this...

Comment: That sounds right - you have assumed the correct things.